# Href no me funciona - pagina con formato php en localhost

Tags: php, html5

Un saludo!
Tengo en siguiente problema, estoy trabajando paginas en .php con wamp, al utilizar href en cualquier etiqueta img, span, a. el navegador no la reconoce y por lo tanto no me re-direcciona al dar click a la imagen o texto y al dar click derecho tampoco permite copiar el url que se asigno pero en la consola del navegador aparece normal

```
<div class="top">
   <div href=".\index.php">
       <img class="top__logo" src=".\img\menu\logo_best.png" href="/" >
   </div> 
   <div class="top__rigth">
      <img class="top__menu icon" src=".\img\menu\icon_menu.png">
      <img class="top__menu login" src=".\img\menu\button_login.png" href=".\signIn.php" target="_blank">     
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para usar una imagen como un enlace en HTML, tienes que usar la etiqueta `<img>` y la etiqueta `<a>` con el atributo `href`. La etiqueta `<img>` es para usar una imagen en una página web y la etiqueta `<a>` es para agregar un enlace.

```
<div class="top">
            <a href=".\index.php"><img class="top__logo" src=".\img\menu\logo_best.png"></a>
            
            <div class="top__rigth">

                <img class="top__menu icon" src=".\img\menu\icon_menu.png">
                <a href=".\signIn.php" target="_blank"><img class="top__menu login" src=".\img\menu\button_login.png"></a>
                
            </div>

        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

En HTML, [la etiqueta para enlaces es `<a>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a), por tanto, debes construir una etiqueta válida que incluya la propiedad `href` y si quieres una imagen la pones dentro de `<a> ... </a>`.

Por ejemplo, aquí, las dos primeras imágenes tienen su enlace. Si lo has entendido, no será difícil poner un enlace para la tercera imagen si fuese necesario.

```html
<div class="top">
  <a href=".\index.php"><img class="top__logo" src=".\img\menu\logo_best.png" /></a>

  <div class="top__rigth">

    <a href=".\signIn.php" target="_blank"><img class="top__menu icon" src=".\img\menu\icon_menu.png"></a>
    <img class="top__menu login" src=".\img\menu\button_login.png" />

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! no lo habia pensado

Answer (score 0):

El atributo href va acompañado de la etiqueta `<a>`
intenta algo asi. `<a href="http://www.carloscordova.com">Visita carlos cordova</a>`

```html
`<a href="http://www.carloscordova.com">Visita carlos cordova</a>`
```